# Issue with OData v3 $batch Endpoint in Web API 2.2 running on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2, odata, iis-7.5

I have a Visual Studio 2013 Web API OData project that I want to get batch processing working with it. I can run it fine on my local desktop from Visual Studio and get a 202 response just fine. When I deploy it to a Windows Server 2008 sp 1 with .NET Framework 4.5 and IIS 7.5, it will run all other commands except for the $batch command.

Here is the request below:

```
POST http://apps/BookingsOData/v3/$batch HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-ID: 1
Host: apps
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_357647d1-a6b5-4e6a-aa73-edfc88d8866e"
Content-Length: 2102

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title />
<author>
<name />
</author>
<updated>2016-09-14T21:21:27Z</updated>
<id />
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:BookingNumber>1400112911</d:BookingNumber>
<d:BookDate m:null="true" />
<d:BookTime m:null="true" />
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
```

On my personal desktop where I developed the program, I get a normal 202 response and see that the record has been added to the database.

When I deploy the application to the server running IIS 7.5, I get the following response with the same request:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 19:01:38 GMT
Content-Length: 262

<Error><Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://apps/BookingsOData/v3/$batch'.</Message><MessageDetail>No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://apps/BookingsOData/v3/$batch'</MessageDetail></Error>
```

Here are the files that I have with the project that may be associated with the OData Batch implementation:
global.asax

```
using BookingsOData.App_Start;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace BoookingsOData
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {
                ODataConfig.Register(config);
                WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ODataConfig.cs

```
using BookingsOData.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Batch;
using Microsoft.Data.Edm;

namespace BookingsOData.App_Start
{
    public class ODataConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Web API configuration and services
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            //builder.Namespace = typeof(BookingRequest).Namespace;
            builder.Namespace = "BookingsOData";
            builder.ContainerName = "GiContext";
            builder.EntitySet<BookingRequest>("BookingRequests");

            // Get EDM model
            var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

            // Setup batch handler
            var batchHandler = new EntityFrameworkBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);

            // Setup OData route
            config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "v3", model, batchHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter;

namespace BookingsOData
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

BookingRequestsController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Routing;
using BookingsOData.Models;
using BookingsOData.App_Start;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;

namespace BookingsOData.Controllers
{
    public class BookingRequestsController : ODataController
    {
        private Entities db = new Entities();

        public BookingRequestsController() : base()
        {
            var _validation = new ODataValidationSettings();
            _validation.AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All;
        }
        // GET: odata/BookingRequests
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<BookingRequest> GetBookingRequests()
        {
            return db.BookingRequests;
        }

        // GET: odata/BookingRequests(5)
        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<BookingRequest> GetBookingRequest([FromODataUri] int key)   
        {
            return SingleResult.Create(db.BookingRequests.Where(bookingRequest => bookingRequest.Id == key));
        }

        // PUT: odata/BookingRequests(5)
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<BookingRequest> patch)
        {
            Validate(patch.GetEntity());

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            BookingRequest bookingRequest = await db.BookingRequests.FindAsync(key);
            if (bookingRequest == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            patch.Put(bookingRequest);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BookingRequestExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Updated(bookingRequest);
        }

        // POST: odata/BookingRequests
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(BookingRequest bookingRequest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.BookingRequests.Add(bookingRequest);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Created(bookingRequest);
        }

        // PATCH: odata/BookingRequests(5)
        [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<BookingRequest> patch)
        {
            Validate(patch.GetEntity());

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            BookingRequest bookingRequest = await db.BookingRequests.FindAsync(key);
            if (bookingRequest == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            patch.Patch(bookingRequest);

            try
            {
                var numSaved = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BookingRequestExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Updated(bookingRequest);
        }

        // DELETE: odata/BookingRequests(5)
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            BookingRequest bookingRequest = await db.BookingRequests.FindAsync(key);
            if (bookingRequest == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.BookingRequests.Remove(bookingRequest);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool BookingRequestExists(int key)
        {
            return db.BookingRequests.Count(e => e.Id == key) > 0;
        }

    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BookingsModel.csdl|res://*/Models.BookingsModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.BookingsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=myDB;user id=user;password=pass;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <clear/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="BookingsOData.OData.customBinding0">
          <binaryMessageEncoding/>
          <httpTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What could be causing the the deployed version not to work with $batch command when all other endpoints work fine?